# Do I need to disconnect from mongoid in unicorn before_fork?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, unicorn

I migrated from mongoid 4 to 5.
In unicorn, do I need to disconnect from mongoid in before_fork?

New mongoid uses the connection pool. Disconnecting wasn't needed in older versions of mongoid.

Comment: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15111902/rails-mongoid-unicorn-config-for-heroku

Comment: Yes, I read that. No answer there, that's why I added another question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In mongoid5 the driver was replaced by mongo-ruby-driver.

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/blob/238db20fcab28848ced85ca6f127c1a2f86877fd/lib/mongo/server/connectable.rb#L99) (+ also verified with cycling the unicorn workers), after fork the connection will be disconnected upon first touch with the db. So you don't have to do that, unless optimising for living connection or such.

HTH